# Delete File in SD Card android with string

Tags: android, string, file, memory, delete-file

I have this string,

```
Cursor c = db.obtenerDatoEjercicio(selecID);
String stringFoto1 = c.getString(6).toString();
```

then stringFoto1 is equals  "file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/neoadnEditGyM/GYM_2.2.jpg"

This file exists.

I want to delete that file on the sd and I used the following code:

```
String stringFoto1 = "file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/neoadnEditGyM/GYM_2.2.jpg"
File archivo1 = new File(stringFoto1);
archivo1.delete();
```

But this doesn't work, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I used another method.

Because when I saved the photo was with the full path.
I put only keep the name and well accessed by "enviroment".

```
 String folderSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures/neoadnEditGyM/";

        Cursor c = db.obtenerDatoEjercicio(selecID);
        String stringFoto1 = c.getString(6).toString();
        String stringFoto2 = c.getString(7).toString();
        File foto1 = new File(folderSD+stringFoto1);
        if (foto1.exists()){
            foto1.delete(); 
            Toast.makeText(this, stringFoto1+" deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        File foto2 = new File (folderSD+stringFoto2);
        if(foto2.exists()){
            foto2.delete();
            Toast.makeText(this, stringFoto2+" deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this:

```
 String strFile = "/sdcard/Pictures/neoadnEditGyM/GYM_2.2.jpg"  
 File file = new File(strFile);
 boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Also, if you are using >1.6 SDK you have to give permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: I have uses-permission. the problem is that string strFile is - "file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/neoadnEditGyM/GYM_2.2.jpg" - because i obtain this string of a db.

Comment: Then try to use the method substring() or replace(), to transform your original string

Comment: I think a leading '/' is required before 'sdcard...' above